# Docker container A access file system of Docker container B without host volume

Tags: docker

Is it possible for a second Docker container to natively access the internal file system of another container if they're running on the same system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without mapping volumes, I think it is not possible!
when you run a container Docker create a namespace for that container and this namespace creates a layer of isolation for the processes of that container meaning their PID sequence, hostname, filesystem, ..... are isolated and for them it is like they are the only processes in that machine
if you need more informations refer to this book: https://www.manning.com/books/kubernetes-in-action

Comment: Thank you.  If I map a host volume, is the rest of the host drive relatively secure from attack from within the container?

Comment: when you map volumes, apparently you lose complete isolation, and it is possible it might be dangerous but it is inevitable sometimes. but I can't find any exploit or vulnerability that use this feature to for example gain access to host namespace and run a code in the host namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared filesystem mounted as volume in two separate containers.

The following command will create a directory called nginxlogs in your current user’s home directory and bindmount it to /var/log/nginx in the container:

```
docker run --name=nginx -d -v ~/nginxlogs:/var/log/nginx -p 5000:80 nginx
```

Then you can perform same operations on another container.
Finally you have to remember that if two separate processes from different containers will try to access files it can cause conflicts.

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for a method without using a host volume but this is useful nonetheless.